# Spring Boot/Spring Security 405 Error: dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm doing my first Spring Security project and I'm just trying to make a user form, user login and then have that form push to a MySQL database. I can't seem to get past this error for a RequestMappingHandlerMapping issue, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm not sure if it's something in Spring Security that is blocking the post request back or if I've mislabeled the controllers. I'd appreciate a fresh set of eyes. Thanks

Error log:

```
2021-08-30 21:56:52.580 DEBUG 18992 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
2021-08-30 21:56:52.582 DEBUG 18992 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
2021-08-30 21:56:52.584 DEBUG 18992 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2021-08-30 21:56:52.602 DEBUG 18992 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

**User Controller**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserDetailsService userDetailsManager;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String displayRegistration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new User());
        return "registration";
    }


    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/registration",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
            )
    public void addUser(@RequestParam Map<String, String> body) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(body.get("username"));
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(body.get("password")));
        user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
        userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
    }

    private String getErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(key);
        String error = "";
        if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            error = "Invalid username and password!";
        } else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
            error = exception.getMessage();
        } else {
            error = "Invalid username and password!";
        }
        return error;
    }
```

**Registration View**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<h1 class="my-5">Create Account</h1>
<body>
<form action="/registration" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username" required>

        <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" required>
        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**SecurityUserDetailsService Controller**

```
@Service
public class SecurityUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not present"));
        return user;
    }

    public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
        userRepository.save((User) user);
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig Controller**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index","*/registration/*").permitAll() //for non-secured pages add to permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your endpoint definition:

- `addUser()` is annotated with `@RequestMapping` but no method defined. This results in a `GET` mapping but you need `POST` here. Either add `method=POST` or better use `@PostMapping`.
- The mapping defines the response content type using `produces` but `addUser()` is declared as `void`. Either remove the `produces` definition or use a return type which can be converted into the desired content type. If you decide to return data, also declare `@ResponseBody` to clarify the result is not a view.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows 'Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED'.  Your 'registration' interface only allows 'GET' methods, and your form uses 'POST'. So the application produces an error and wants to redirect an error interface named 'error', but hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your @RequestMapping annotation.

Use this

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/registration",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below. one more thing set object of any value you can write in the service layer it is better for coding. mostly business logic are write in service layer.

```
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user, Model model) {
        user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
        userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
        return "redirect:/registration";
    }
```